# GAE Datastore Consistency (Development Mode)?

Tags: google-app-engine, datastore

My GWT/J application works flawlessly on GAE, writes are strongly consistent, but when running in development mode, writes are only eventually consistent and may take up to 15s to appear.  This is creating some test difficulties.

Could this be because of my modest development hardware? (It is attempting to provide strong consistency, but two cores is not enough to run the Datastore and web server..) Or is there a setting that would enable me to get "immediate" writes?

Or is this working as intended and I need to implement entity groups to get guaranteed consistency everywhere?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you need to implement entity groups to get guaranteed consistency everywhere.

If you are ok with eventual consistency, you can force the guaranteed consistency in your tests.  But be aware that this won't be representative of the real world.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting#Writing_HRD_Datastore_Tests